# CommunityToolkit: is it possible to have a readonly property?

Tags: c#, windows-community-toolkit

I am trying the CommmunityToolkit MVVM.

I would like to have a read only property so it wouldn't be changed in the view because of the binding. I want to ensure only the view model can change it and to notify to the view.

Until now, I was using this way:

```
    private int myVar;
    public int MyProperty
    {
        get { return myVar; }
        private set { myVar = value; }
    }
```

But I don't know if it is possible with the toolkit, because I have tried this:

```
readonly int MyProperty
```

But I get an error because it is readonly.

Is there some way to declare a readonly property with the toolkit?

Thanks.

Comment: Set the `Mode` property of the binding to `OneWay` in your Xaml. The property can be defined as a regular property with a get and set part without the readonly modifier.  That should enable you to change the value from the view model but not from the view.

Comment: Yes, I know in the view I could set the Mode, but that makes it depend on the view, and I would prefer that the view model could ensure that it is not changed from the outside.